# Window resizing in Mac application development

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos

Hello everyone I want to know that how could I design my user-interface relatively.I mean to say that if I resize my window its  subviews should resize accordingly without overlapping each other.In .Net I remember that we use rows and columns to design our user-interface.What is the proper design pattern in xcode so our application is screen-size independent.As far as I know for this we will have to set the sizes of our views programmatically.We can not do it in interface builder.Any suggestions please!

Answer (score 1):

Read the Setting a View’s Autosizing Behaviour section in [Interface Builder User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/Layout/Layout.html). You want to configure the autosizing rules of your views with the springs & struts mechanism. This can be done either in Interface Builder or programatically via autoresizing masks.

[image: Interface Builder autosizing rules]